# Extension on SaasTenant could not be updated [ABP Framework]

Tags: c#, typescript, abp

I want to add a new property into a new column of the `SaasTenants` using ABP Commercial *(front end is Angular)*. For so far I've added a EF Core mapping *(see code below)*, created a migrations and updated the database.

```cs
ObjectExtensionManager.Instance.MapEfCoreProperty<Tenant, string>(
    TenantExtraPropetiesName.newProp,
    (entityBuilder, propertyBuilder) =>
    {
        propertyBuilder
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(10)
            .HasColumnName(TenantExtraPropetiesName.newProp);
    }
);
```

This property must be edited into the SaaS tenant create form as an additional field. I'm using this code for it.

```
import { ePropType, FormProp, FormPropList, } from '@abp/ng.theme.shared/extensions';
import { eSaasComponents, SaasCreateFormPropContributors } from '@volo/abp.ng.saas';
import { SaasTenantDto } from '@volo/abp.ng.saas/lib/proxy/host/dtos';

// Additional actions for tenant management.

const newCreateFormProp = new FormProp<SaasTenantDto>({
    name: 'newCreateFormProp',
    type: ePropType.String,
    displayName: '::newCreateFormProp'
});

export function newCreateFromPropContributor(actionList: FormPropList<SaasTenantDto>): void {
    actionList.addTail(newCreateFormProp);
}

export const tenantEntityCreateFormPropContributors: SaasCreateFormPropContributors = {
    [eSaasComponents.Tenants]: [
        newCreateFromPropContributor
    ]
};
```

and linked it into the `AppRoutingModule` as follow:

```
// Removed some lines.
{
    path: 'saas',
    loadChildren: () => import('@volo/abp.ng.saas').then(m => m.SaasModule.forLazy({
        createFormPropContributors: tenantEntityCreateFormPropContributors
    }))
},
```

The problem now is when I click on Save inside the *New tenant* modal, the `newProp` will be an empty string. My guess is that the `SaasTenantCreateDto` not correctly maps to `SaaSTenant`. So how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for a while, I've found next solution to fix my problem. First I needed to chain this method to `ObjectExtensionManager.Instance.MapEfCoreProperty`

```cs
.AddOrUpdateProperty<string>(
    new Type[]
    {
        typeof(SaasTenantDto),
        typeof(SaasTenantCreateDto)
    },
    TenantExtraPropetiesName.newProp
);
```

Inside my `newCreateFormProp` I need to add the property `isExtra` with value `true`.

```
const newCreateFormProp = new FormProp<SaasTenantDto>({
    name: 'newCreateFormProp',
    type: ePropType.String,
    displayName: '::newCreateFormProp'
    isExtra: true
});
```

Both actions did solve my issue.